# Why did Microsoft change the programatic behavious of the windows 11 command prompt in the release on 11 Nov 22?

Tags: command-prompt

A few days ago I built myself a simple windows console utility in C++ to view a data stream in an more visual way. I used some basic windows function calls to do things like position the cursor, change the screen colors and draw some boxes using the line characters.

As you can see two days ago (8th) it was working nicely...

[image]

Now last night (9th) my windows 11 laptop restarted over night with what I assume to be a windows automatic update which often happen on Wednesdays.

Now my same program, I did not re-compile it, is behaving very differently with the command prompt console (cmd).

[image]

What have they been meddling with to change the stock behavior of the command prompt ? They have defiantly been updating stuff because now the command prompt title line is different. It now has options to open more sessions by clicking on the new '+' tab.

Can default behavior be restored or do MS expect everyone to re-write working code to suit there undocumented changes ?

Comment: In Win OS, there is something known as restore points. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

This is a BUG in the behaviour of the new "Tabbed" command windows, I'm raising an issue with MS, as I've had the same issue for a few weeks now.

Luckily there is a way to get back the old behaviour:

Right click on the empty space of the title bar and select `"Settings"`
This should bring you to the ***Settings->Startup screen***

Change the `"Default terminal application"` to ***"Windows Console Host"***

Click `"Save"`

Comment: Have MS created a trouble ticket ? I didn't know how or if they would even listen to a niggle of a single insignificant user.