# Microsoft changed the way the console works in recent Win11 update - Bug or Feature?

Tags: command-prompt

Following on from a recent experience where my console program suddenly behaved differently after a windows update :
[Why did Microsoft change the programatic behavious of the windows 11 command prompt in the release on 11 Nov 22?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74387158/why-did-microsoft-change-the-programatic-behavious-of-the-windows-11-command-pro?noredirect=1#comment131320974_74387158)

I have found that using SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx() now longer appears to change the size of the console window.

I made a test program and ran it on my old Win10 m/c and on Win11 where the console (CMD) has changed.

On win10 the window size is changed :
[image]

On win11 it is not (exactly the same EXE) :
[image]

So how can you change the screen size now with Win11 ? Is this a Bug or new MS Feature ?

My test code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>



//Returns the last Win32 error, in string format. Returns an empty string if there is no error.
const char *GetLastErrorStr(DWORD errorMessageID)
{
    #define BUFSIZ  100
    static char buffer[BUFSIZ+1];
    //Get the error message ID, if any.
    //DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    if(errorMessageID == 0) {
        return ""; //No error message has been recorded
    }
    
    LPSTR messageBuffer = NULL;

    //Ask Win32 to give us the string version of that message ID.
    //The parameters we pass in, tell Win32 to create the buffer that holds the message for us (because we don't yet know how long the message string will be).
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                                 NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);
    
    //Copy the error message into a buffer
    size_t s;
    if(size > BUFSIZ) {
      s = BUFSIZ;
    } else {
      s = size;
    }
    strncpy(buffer, messageBuffer, s);
    
    //Free the Win32's string's buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);
            
    return buffer;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  HANDLE co;
  HANDLE ci;
  DWORD gs = 0;
  DWORD ss = 0;
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX currentInfoEx { sizeof currentInfoEx };
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX newInfoEx { sizeof newInfoEx };
  COORD consiz;

  // Set the screen size we want
  consiz.X = 110;
  consiz.Y = 44;

  // Get streams
  co = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  ci = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);


  // Get screen info
  if(GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(co, &currentInfoEx) == 0) {
    gs = GetLastError();
  }

  // Set screen info
  newInfoEx = currentInfoEx;
  //newInfoEx.dwSize.X = consiz.X;
  //newInfoEx.dwSize.Y = consiz.Y;
  newInfoEx.srWindow.Left = newInfoEx.srWindow.Left;
  newInfoEx.srWindow.Top = newInfoEx.srWindow.Top;
  newInfoEx.srWindow.Right = newInfoEx.srWindow.Left + consiz.X - 1;
  newInfoEx.srWindow.Bottom = newInfoEx.srWindow.Top + consiz.Y - 1;
  newInfoEx.wAttributes = BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_INTENSITY;
  if(SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(co, &newInfoEx) == 0) {
    ss = GetLastError();
  }

  // Print results
  if(gs != 0) {
    printf("Get Screen Size error = %s\n", GetLastErrorStr(gs));
  }
  if(ss != 0) {
    printf("Set Screen Size error = %s\n", GetLastErrorStr(ss));
  }
  printf("Original - Size %d/%d Max %d/%d L/T R/B %d/%d %d/%d\n",
    currentInfoEx.dwSize.X, 
    currentInfoEx.dwSize.Y,
    currentInfoEx.dwMaximumWindowSize.X,
    currentInfoEx.dwMaximumWindowSize.Y,
    currentInfoEx.srWindow.Left,
    currentInfoEx.srWindow.Top,
    currentInfoEx.srWindow.Right,
    currentInfoEx.srWindow.Bottom
    );
  printf("New      - Size %d/%d Max %d/%d L/T R/B %d/%d %d/%d\n",
    newInfoEx.dwSize.X, 
    newInfoEx.dwSize.Y, 
    newInfoEx.dwMaximumWindowSize.X,
    newInfoEx.dwMaximumWindowSize.Y,
    newInfoEx.srWindow.Left,
    newInfoEx.srWindow.Top,
    newInfoEx.srWindow.Right,
    newInfoEx.srWindow.Bottom
    );
  // Wait for key
  printf("Press Enter : ");
  getchar();

  return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your console application with Windows Console Host, not the new Windows Terminal.  There's a setting in the Windows control panel to switch between the two or you can right-click to choose which to open with as a one-off change.